# Unable to run ant from another directory

Tags: java, windows, ant, path, environment-variables

I am making a small java project with a jboss server and using ant for building the project.
I have already set the environment variables ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME correctly and checked them in cmd prompt.
The PATH is also set.
The only problem is that I am not able to run ant from any other directory other than ant\bin.
I am getting the following message in command prompt:

"'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

However if I try to run it from the ant\bin directory i get the following message:

"Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
 Build failed"

which is correct as i have not made the build.xml file.
thanx.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The PATH is set, but to which value?

Comment: the PATH is set to ANT_HOME\bin;JAVA_HOME\bin;JBOSS_HOME\bin.

Comment: You need to use $ANT_HOME on Unix, or %ANT_HOME% on windows, else ANT_HOME is take literally. (same for the other ones, of course)

Comment: yeah i know..i used %ANT_HOME% in windows 7

Comment: Suggest that you include the output of echo for each of the variables in your question body and not in various comments.  Further note that this appears to be a windows environment question.  Obviously we know ant works as advertised on windows (agreed?)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  You need to add the bin directory from ant to the PATH.

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2"
if [ -e $ANT_HOME ]; then
    export PATH=${ANT_HOME}/bin:$PATH
fi
```

Comment: I have already done that in the system variables.

Comment: This is how to add ant to the path on unix.  If you are on Windows it's different.  Type this command: echo %PATH% and show us the output.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\sy
swow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\Wire
lessCommon\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JBOSS_HOME%\bin

Comment: you can see at the end that the path is set. is anything wrong in that part?

Comment: Yes the environment variables JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME, and JBOSS_HOME aren't evaluating.  You need to define these as environment variables. try executing `echo %ANT_HOME%`

Comment: already defined them as user variables.
doing "echo %ANT_HOME%" is giving the correct path where my ant directory is located.

Comment: Well try putting the ant_home bin path instead of the %ANT_HOME%\bin.  It doesn't seem to be working for you.  Your question is really how to use variables in a Windows PATH?

Comment: in command prompt, type "set path" and see if it is containing the correct path for ant.

Comment: @j4y hey it worked..%ANT_HOME% was not working..I entered the path for it and it worked.. Thank You